# How to import font family files properly react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fonts

I cannot import my font files, dont know why is not working.

Here what I did:

1. Create font folder and added font-files inside

```
 fonts/avenir.woff
 fonts/avenir.woff2
```

2. in body setup font-faimily

```
 body {
    font-family: Avenir;
    //  Open-Sans, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: ${colors.offWhite};
  }
```

3. Call the font-face:

```
  @import url("http://fast.fonts.net/t/1.css?apiType=css&projectid=7ba9e0a7-abe8-437c-a682-27fa19a01908");
  @font-face{
      font-family:"Avenir LT W01_35 Light1475496";
      src:url("./fonts/avenir.woff2") format("woff2"),url("./fonts/avenir.woff") format("woff");
  }
```

And still does not work

Where I am making a mistake?

Comment: In `@font-face` you named your font `Avenir LT W01_35 Light1475496` but in body you are trying to apply font named `Avenir`. Read more and see some examples at [@font-face on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).

Comment: @Jax-p thank for the answer I am on it